# Linked Service with self-hosted integration runtime is not supported in data flow in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Step to reproduce:

1. I created a Copy Data first in the pipeline to simple transfer CSV files frol Azure VM to Azure Blob storage. I always use IRPOC1 as a connection via integration runtime and connect using SAS URI and SAS Token to my Blob Storage
2. After validate and run my first Copy Data, I successfully have CSV file transfer from my VM to Blob storage
3. I tried to add a new Data Flow after the Copy Data activity
4. In my Data Flow, my source is the Blob storage containing the CSV files transferred from VM, my Sink is my Azure SQL Database with successful connection
5. However, when I ran validation, I got the error message on my Data Flow Source:

   Linked Service with self-hosted integration runtime is not supported in data flow.

I saw someone replied on Microsoft Azure Document issue Github that I need to use Copy Data to transfer data to Blob first. Then use the source from this blob with data. This is what I did but I still have the same error. Could you please let me know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Data Flow source dataset must use a Linked Service that uses an Azure IR, not a self-hosted IR.

Go to the dataset in your data flow Source, click "Open". In the dataset page, click "Edit" next to Linked Service.

In the Linked Service dialog, make sure you are using an Azure Integration Runtime, not a Self-hosted IR.

[image]

Comment: Hello @Mark Kromer thank yoou very much for your reply. I will try this workaround.

Comment: Thank you very much. This workaround resolved my issue.

Comment: I got around this by moving my files from on prem file share to blob storage.

Comment: after the file is moved to blob storage, we should not use self hosted runtime. use Azure IR in data flow for source dataset

Comment: Hi, i am also facing similar but my source is ADLS gen2 to copy the data to on prem sql, i got self hosted runtime to test the connection but while validate i am getting alert message for Linked service with Self-hosted Integration runtime is not supported dataflow. please suggest

Comment: To connect to on-prem data with data flows, use the Azure IR with Vnet instead of self-hosted IR as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-managed-virtual-network-on-premise-sql-server

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT is this limited to ADF or can be used with Synapse analytics as well ?

Comment: Works in both ADF & Synapse